# Shadow of my model glitches and looks weird

Tags: modeling, rendering, eevee-render-engine, shadows

Good evening, I recently found a problem with my model's shadow: the shadow glitches when camera moves, and it generally looks weird:
[image]
And here is a shader I tried to use on it:
[image]
I tried to recalculate normals, use the "Subdivision surface" modifier and change render engine, but it didn't help. I would be grateful if someone explained to me what the problem might be.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by glitching? In the image that you have provided, everything looks fine. Can you provide an image of when it glitches? Or even better a screen recording maybe?

Comment: Yes, sure, here's screen record: https://imgur.com/a/H5sRLcQ

Answer (score 0):

This flickering behaviour is kinda completely normal while using Eevee.

Basically the lights are being recalculated every time you orbit. Once you stop moving around, the lights are calculated and usually within a second everything settles down.

This flickering is more prominent on slower computers as they are just not able to keep up with the calculating of lighting according to speed of your orbiting.

But don't worry. This will not be visible in the render if that's a question which arises in your mind. This only happens while orbiting and moving around the scene.